# Designing a permissions based security model

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, permissions, roles

I work on a vb.net winforms app where we currently are using simple roles for security. We enable/disable specific controls based on if the current user has the required role. We are to the point where this is no longer granular enough.

Our application is based on different physical locations we call sites. A user might have permission to do something (for example, edit a site's configuration) at one site but not another. Therefore, we now need to lookup permissions based on current user AND current site. Also, a certain user's permissions may be very specific to themselves ie. no other user's permissions are exactly the same as another user's. Therefore we need a security model that's more permissions based rather than role based.

What's the best way to design a new permissions model that can meet these requirements? I want to make sure that it's easy to implement the checking in the code (I don't want a million if statements sprinkled in our SetUIPermissions methods) and we don't want to have to update every user (400+ and counting) each time we add a new permission. Because of this last requirement I think we need to keep the idea of roles but possibly add/remove exceptions for particular permissions for specific users.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with the roles and permissions.  It's a relatively common solution to have a role refer to a set of "default" permissions; by having a user have a role and a set of permissions, you allow for the role to be overridden by the set of permissions specifically granted / revoked for that user.  This gives reasonable flexibility and granularity, and supports your situation of adding new permissions (in the role) without needing to touch every user.

Comment: This is essentially what I've designed. We're going to keep the idea of roles, add permissions that each role gets and let there be positive and negative exceptions for each user/site combination's role.